# Making sql queries to search through a MTG database

Tags: sql, database

**Im making a MTG card database for my class**

I have 5 tables:
`card` holds a `cardId`, `name`, `text`, `power`, `toughness`, `rarity`, `manacost`, `setId`, `CMC`.  cardId is the primary key

`color` holds a `colorId` and `color`. color is the string, colorId is the primary key
`type` holds a `typeId` and `type`. Type is a string, typeId is the primary key
`card_colors` is a linking table that holds entry pairs of `cardId` and `colorId`
`card_types` is a linking table that holds entry pairs of `cardId` and `typeId`.

How can I search for cards by name, and have their respective types and colors to show up in one row? Currently my query shows multiple entries of each card, one for every color.

Here's my current query:

```
 SELECT card.name, type.name, color.color
 FROM card, card_types, card_color
 JOIN type, color
 ON (card.cardId = card_types.cardId) AND (card.cardId = card_color.cardId)
 WHERE card.name LIKE "ENTER NAME HERE";
```

If you want to check it out you can find my .sqlite file here:
http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/446996/mtg_database.sqlite

Comment: I don't think you can do that using sql alone. The problem is that you need to append a number of unknown columns to your output based on colors and types. I would suggest creating cursors for each of these queries separately and collating all the data in your favourite programming language

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT crd.NAME AS CardName, 
       ct.NAME AS CardType, 
       cl.color AS CardColor
FROM card crd
 INNER JOIN card_types ct ON(crd.cardId=ct.cardId)
 INNER JOIN  card_color cl ON(crd.cardId=cl.cardId)
WHERE crd.NAME='%ENTER NAME HERE%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread, but what you are looking for is PIVOT.  You can use something like below to pivot the colors out wide of the cards.  You can do the same thing with types or whatever other attribute has the potential to have multiple values.  While this code demonstrates pivoting a finite and known number of attributes, you could dynamically populate a variable with a list of all distinct values and build a dynamic T-SQL string.  Additionally you can use all of this to join to your lookup tables to get the verbose card information.

```
select cardid, [1] , [2] , [3] , [4] , [5] 
from 
(
    select cardid, colorid, 
        row_number() over (partition by cardid order by cardid) as rownum
    from card_colors) a
pivot
(
    max(colorid) for rownum in ( [1] , [2] , [3] , [4] , [5] )
)as pvt;
```